# «...журналист и писатель, она была ещё очень интеллигентным человеком...». Стоит ли ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Талантливый журналист и писатель, она была ещё очень интеллигентным, доброжелательным  и чутким человеком.

Comment: Всё замечательно, вопросов к пунктуации нет. Будучи талантливым журналистом, она была ещё и...

Comment: ок, спасибо!!!!

Comment: Она вроде как опровергла фр. публикацию о своей смерти.

Comment: это местный крымский журналист.....)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая на месте, но необходимо добавить "и" после "еще"

**Талантливый журналист и писатель, она была ещё и очень интеллигентным, доброжелательным и чутким человеком.**

Comment: Она была к тому же ещё и ну очень... Кто больше.

Comment: "...он был и впрямь очень талантлив, ― недаром попал на старости лет в Художественный театр, ― но он был еще и очень умный, проницательный человек". [И. А. Бунин. ]

Comment: @Shampar - сравните "Он был еще красив" (не успел стать некрасивым) и "Он был еще и красив" (обладал красотой в дополнение к другим достоинствам)

Comment: Был ещё интеллигентным = Не успел стать не интеллигентным? Напоминает сообщение о самочувствии зверей после переезда в другой город: «Их оберегали, но они всё-таки успели испугаться».